# if an attribute is not present in map, How to replace the values in template string using strsubsitutor as null or empty string

Tags: java, apache-commons, string-substitution, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

I have a string

```
String templateString = "The ${animal} jumps over the ${target}.";
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

But there is no entry for attr target in valuesMap.
Final resolvedString would be
The quick brown fox jumps over the ${target}.

Instead of ${target}, it need to be empty. Values in templatestring which doesn't have key in map should be empty or null.

required
The quick brown fox jumps over the.

How to handle this

Answer (score 1):

Your `Map<String,String> valuesMap` contains just the couple key, value `"animal", "quick brown fox"`, you have to add the couple `"target", ""` to your map like below:

```
String templateString = "The ${animal} jumps over the ${target}.";
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
valuesMap.put("target", ""); //<-- adding the new couple to the map
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

Comment: Just now checked in documentation of strsubstitutor. We can use delimiter to set default value in template string

Replying to your Answer, If i get that map from an external api, which doesn't include key if its null. How do you proceed this case?
(keys are dynamic)

Comment: @KarthikCkn If I understand well you do not want to modify the original map from the external api and set an empty default value, in this case you can use `:-` operator in your string template with an empty default value like The `${animal} jumps over the ${target:-}`.